# Jquery Slider that controls jquery audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I am working on an audio slider for a jquery player the goal is to get the audio slider to control the volume. The audio player is initiated using Jquery instead of the audio tags and has the class .play For some reason the slider isn't changing volume.

Edit: Working Solution - http://jsfiddle.net/jeffd/2fjnmdkb/2/

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffd/2fjnmdkb/1/

```
 $(".play").on('click', function () {
     var key = $(this).attr('key');
     EvalSound(this, key);
     var this_play = $(this);
     $(".play").each(function () {
         if ($(this)[0] != this_play[0]) {
             $(this).removeClass("pause");
         }
     });
     $(this).toggleClass("pause");
 });

 var thissound = new Audio();
 var currentKey;

 function EvalSound(el, key) {

     thissound.addEventListener('ended', function () {
         // done playing
         $(el).removeClass("pause");
     });

     if (currentKey !== key) thissound.src = "http://99centbeats.com/1e4cb5f584d055a0992385c1b2155786/" + key + ".mp3";
     currentKey = key;

     if (thissound.paused) thissound.play();
     else thissound.pause();
     thissound.currentTime = 0;
     currentPlayer = thissound;


 }
$(".volume_slider").slider({
    value  : 75,
    step   : 1,
    range  : 'min',
    min    : 0,
    max    : 100,
    slide  : function(){
        var value = $(".volume_slider").slider("value");
        $('.play').prop('volume', (value/100));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed .play selector to the var thissound and it works

Working Js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffd/2fjnmdkb/2/

```
$(".play").on('click', function () {
     var key = $(this).attr('key');
     EvalSound(this, key);
     var this_play = $(this);
     $(".play").each(function () {
         if ($(this)[0] != this_play[0]) {
             $(this).removeClass("pause");
         }
     });
     $(this).toggleClass("pause");
 });

 var thissound = new Audio();
 var currentKey;

 function EvalSound(el, key) {

     thissound.addEventListener('ended', function () {
         // done playing
         $(el).removeClass("pause");
     });

     if (currentKey !== key) thissound.src = "http://99centbeats.com/1e4cb5f584d055a0992385c1b2155786/" + key + ".mp3";
     currentKey = key;

     if (thissound.paused) thissound.play();
     else thissound.pause();
     thissound.currentTime = 0;
     currentPlayer = thissound;


 }
$(".volume_slider").slider({
    value  : 75,
    step   : 1,
    range  : 'min',
    min    : 0,
    max    : 100,
    slide  : function(){
        var value = $(".volume_slider").slider("value");
        thissound.volume = (value / 100);
    }
});
```